# Why is plotly producing a histogram that seems to be incorrect?

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, plotly-python

```
import plotly.express as px

px.histogram(purchase_data,x='Log_Final Price',color='Sale')
```

Plot with plotly express
[image]

Same Plot with Seaborn

```
sns.histplot(purchase_data,x='Log_Final Price',hue='Sale')
```

You can clearly see, for Sale='Yes' and Sale='Np', plotly is giving completely opposite plot.

[image]

Comment: The first plot shows _stacked_ bars (`barmode='relative'` which is the default with px, or `barmode='stack'` with go), and the second shows _overlaid_ bars (`barmode='overlay'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plotly histogram isn't incorrect, it's just stacked. And it will resemble your seaborn histogram more closely  if you include:

```
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'overlay')
fig.update_traces(opacity=0.50)
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Code

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x='total_bill', color = 'sex')
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'overlay')
fig.update_traces(opacity=0.50)
fig.show()
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the _barmode_ propertiy of plotly corresponds to _multiple_ in seaborn.  It seems like `multiple='layer'` is the default in seaborn and corresponds to `barmode='overlay'` in plotly, so you can set either `barmode='overlay'` to the 1st one, or set `multiple='stack'` to the 2nd. But it's just an assumption.